# What's the most efficient way to sleep in Python?

Tags: python, performance, select, time, sleep

What would be better ?

`time.sleep(delayTime)`

or

`select.select([],[],[],delayTime)`

Are they equivalent ? Is select more efficient?

Comment: Efficient on what resource?

Comment: CPU usage, precision.

Comment: What prevents you from testing and comparing both?

Comment: Well, I profiled them, and they use almost the same amount of cpu. But I don't really know what's the difference between them. For example it is better to use sleep over select for some specific cases ? or the opposite ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on what your trying to achieve:

```
time.sleep(delayTime)
```

- Action: Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds.
- Any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine

```
select.select([],[],[],delayTime)
```

This is a straightforward interface to the Unix `select()` system call. The first three arguments are sequences of ‘waitable objects’:

- **rlist**: wait until ready for reading
- **wlist**: wait until ready for writing
- **xlist**: wait for an “exceptional condition”

So now, that we understand the two interfaces we can understand that the answer depends on the purpose: 
If all you want to do is to suspend the current thread - the first option is simpler. But if there are objects to wait on - use the second method.
In temp of efficiency - I don't think there are differences if all you are looking for is the simplest use-case (just suspend the main thread).

Answer (score 5):

Pretty simple to hackup a test in python with called to `timeit`, but I love ipython for quick tests (http://ipython.org/). Here's my results:

```
$ ipython
import time,select

%timeit time.sleep(0)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 655 ns per loop

%timeit select.select([],[],[],0)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 902 ns per loop
```

But if you don't have access to ipython, and would prefer native `timeit` from command line:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "import time,select" "time.sleep(0)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.583 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "import time,select" "select.select([],[],[],0)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.777 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

How you defining the efficiency? In most of the cases, the sleep and select have been using to observe if there space/buffer. If the space is not available, then we have option to wait and see when the buffer will be empty and we can execute our action.
The sleep() internally select(). So, I think it matters with which you are comfortable with, I guess.